# iPhone Shape Library

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c, shapes

In Java there is a interface called `Shape`, which is used to define a generic shape.
I am hoping to find something similar in objective-c, but have not had that much luck so far.

Before I rewrite the wheel, Can I please Know if such a library exists? (Maybe built into the `CoreGraphics` framework?)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start reading this [Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).